# Authorize and customauthenticationattribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have authentication handler in my project that is for SignalR, and I have `CustomAuthenticationAttribute` for my controllers, the problem is if I try to call controller it excutes authentication handler first and validates it, if it is validate then only it calling customauthenticationattribute, but I need to execute `CustomAuthenticationAttribute` if I hit the controller.

````cs
//start up configuration
services.AddAuthentication("SignalR")
     .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, SignalRCustomAuthentication>("SignalR", null);```

// authentication handler
public class SignalRCustomAuthentication : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>   
{   
    public SignalRCustomAuthentication
           (
           IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
           ILoggerFactory logger,
           UrlEncoder encoder,
           ISystemClock clock,
        )
           : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        jwtTokenConfig = _jwtTokenConfig;
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        try
        {               
            var accessToken = Request.Query["access_token"].ToString();         

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                
                    var jwtPrincipal = ValidatedToken(accessToken);

                    if (jwtPrincipal != null)
                    {
                        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(jwtPrincipal, Scheme.Name);                           
                        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
                    }}
                else
                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized"));
        }
    }
}
````

Custom authorize attribute:

```cs
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{       
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {            
        try
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var tokenValue))
            {
                string authHeaderToken = tokenValue;

                string[] token = authHeaderToken.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);       
            
                if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("AuthenticationStatus", Common.Utility.UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS);
                    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;                       
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                   context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("AuthenticationStatus", Common.Utility.AUTHORIZED);
                    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Success; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question its not clear ? you don't want to execute `SignalRCustomAuthentication` for your controllers right ?

Comment: hi @CodingMytra actually signalrCustom authentication for signalR authentication, I have Written another custom authentication(It's an attribute) for controller , If I have added[CustomAuthentication] attribute above controller, if I hit the controller it is not excuting [CustomAuthentication] attribute first, first it excuting the Signalrauthentication then only it goes to [customauthentication], but I want to excute [Customauthentication] first if I hit the controller

Comment: sorry but i didn't get the meaning of your comment.

Comment: I have edited previous comment please read it. @CodingMytra

Comment: understood, you can't control order but if you can skip the SignalRCustomAuthentication for your controllers

Comment: I can execute for signalr authentication for controller , but I am having different kind of validations for signalr and controller.@CodingMytra

Comment: see ans below i have given probable solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can skip your authentication for controllers

```
protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    try
    {   
        // here you add logic to check if path belongs to controllers 
        // if yes the don't execute rest of code
        if(!IsControllerReqeust(request)) // you need to impement this method
        {
           var accessToken = Request.Query["access_token"].ToString();  
          // rest of your authentication code
        }
    }
}
```